# how to add and divide results from sql queries

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have a database which I am trying to create a webpage summary widget for. I am using MS Webmatrix and razor.

I have several select queries set as variables, then my html asks for their values as a string and displays them. So far so good.
Now I want to add two results together, then subtract a third. EG: add todays processed orders ( I called it itotl) and todays partly processed orders (ppr) and subtract todays credits (ctotl).
Thus, i want (itotl + ppr) - ctotl.
If I try and do this by entering the @itotl and @ppr variables etc in my html, it fails.
There will be a simple, industry best practice way to do it but I'm only learning, and the hard way at that!

Any Suggestions? I can paste the whole code in here if it will help.
Here:
`@{

    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

    Page.Title = "SCOREBOARD";

    var db = Database.Open("data");

    var itot = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) from dbo.DR_TRANS where TRANSDATE = 41192 and SUBTOTAL >0");

    var isum = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(subtotal) from dbo.DR_TRANS where TRANSDATE = 41192 and Subtotal >0");

    var qsum = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(subtotal) from dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE = 41192 and Subtotal >0");

    var ppr = db.QueryValue("select sum(subtotal) from dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE = 41192 and SUBTOTAL  >0 and status = 1");

    var psum = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(subtotal) from dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE = 41192 and Status =1");

    var qtot = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE = 41192 and SUBTOTAL  >0");

    var ctot = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) from dbo.DR_TRANS where TRANSDATE = 41192 and TRANSTYPE = 1 and SUBTOTAL <0");

    var csum = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(SUBTOTAL) from dbo.DR_TRANS where TRANSDATE = 41192 and TRANSTYPE = 1 and SUBTOTAL <0");

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="15"></META>;

}`
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<html lang="en">`
   `<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title></title>

        <style>

            .column1 {color: blue; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.6em;}

            .column2 {color: red;}

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p>@qsum.ToString() Quotes:

            <span class=@(qtot > 20000 ? "column1" : "column2")>@qtot.ToString("C")</span>

        </p>

        <p>@psum.ToString() Partly Processed:

            <span class=@(ppr > 18000 ? "column1" : "column2")>@ppr.ToString("C")</span>

        </p>

        <p>@isum.ToString() Invoices:

            <span class=@(itot > 18000 ? "column1" : "column2")>@itot.ToString("C")</span>

        </p>

        <p>@csum.ToString() Credits:

            <span class=@(ctot > 18000 ? "column1" : "column2")>@ctot.ToString("C")</span>

        </p>

        <p>Nett Sales:</p>

    </body>

</html>`

How do I get my markup to show tidily in stack? This has rendered a little hard to read!

Comment: @Bevan In the code portion of your page, but after the query statements, add ther row `var xxxx = itotl + ppr - ctotl;`, where _xxxx_ is the new value you want display. BTW, I don't see _itotl_ and _ctotl_ among the variables you have declared.

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? What code are you using that "fails" and how does it fail? Error messages? More details required please.

Comment: Sorry, 'it fails' means the browser displays the message "Compilation error" and gripes about my code on the lines where I have added the variables mentioned. @GmG has the answer.

Comment: @GmG - This works unless one or the other is 0 or Null. Then, it throws the toys out of the pram and screams 'Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'System.DBNull' How do I get it to display 0 if 0 is indeed the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps or not, but values can always be added, multiplied, etc. within the SQL statement itself, and then you can even give it an alias (using AS):

```
SELECT ((itotl - ppr) + ctotl) AS newTotal FROM tableName WHERE .....etc.
```

It seems like if this was going to be helpful to you, someone would have said it already, or you already know how to do this and it doesn't help you here for some reason, but maybe I don't understand the question?

Anyway, hope I can help, if not let me know, and I will try again :)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the code portion of your page, but after the query statements, add the row
    `var xxxx = itotl + ppr - ctotl;,` where xxxx is the new value you want display. BTW, I don't see itotl and ctotl among the variables you have declared. – GmG Oct 12 at 10:01

This was the correct answer.